# Is there somthing like an ampersand in c that I can use in javascript to function parameters?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pass Variables by Reference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744611/pass-variables-by-reference-in-javascript)

I desperately look for a solution. I have a javascript project to finish and the only thing that stays in my way is this little thing. I only need something like and ampersand in c to put next to a function parameter so it be passed by reference and it would change outside of the function.

Now I know there are other ways. But in my case this is the only thing that will help me.
This is a program that creates binary search trees and I originally made it in c++ but I need to convert it to javascript cause I will show how the tree is generated while the code executes. This is my project. So to create the binary structure only something like an ampersand would help me.

```
function nod()
{
    var info;
    var left;
    var right;
}

var rad;
rad = new nod();
rad = null;

function create(rad,x) // create(nod *&rad, int x) in c++
{
    if(rad==null)
    {
        rad = new nod();
        rad.info = x ;
        rad.left = rad.right = null;
    }
    else
    {
        if(x < rad.info)
        {
            create(rad.left,x);
        }
        else
        { 
            create(rad.right,x);
        }
    }
}

function read(rad) // read(nod *&rad) in c++
{
    var input = [
                    0,
                    10,
                    2,
                    1,
                    8,
                    9,
                    4,
                    5,
                    3,
                    6,
                    20,
                    11,
                    30,
                    21,
                    31,
                    22,
                    23,
                ];
    var i;
    for(i=1;i<=16;i++)
    {
        create(rad,input[i]);
    }
}

read(rad);
```

Comment: You never say what problem you have that passing by address will solve. Please describe your problem more thoroughly

Comment: oh sorry.. my problem is that.. i need that recursive structure because i need to be able to start from rad and get all the nods like rad at the start is 10.. rad.left is 1 rad.left.right is 2 rad.right is 20... and i need to access it that way.. its a must for my project.... i need it to be that way because i'm making a web page that will have the c++ code displayed on the left and on the right i will have the binary tree generated as the code executes.. by clicking on a button it will execute a line of code... and i need it to be almost identical to the c code so have the minimum of problems

Answer (score 0):

In javascript objects are passed by reference. So try passing your values as objects.
Hint: Try passing it like this {value:your_value}

Comment: Down vote, strings and other primitive types are NOT passed by reference. As you stated, objects ARE

Comment: Ok thanks, added that. I thought they were passed by reference looking at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308624/pass-a-string-by-reference-in-javascript

Comment: *Nothing* is passed by reference in JavaScript. Read the accepted answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: The confusion here stems from the fact that what's passed is a reference, but if you reassign the variable inside the function (instead of modifying its contents), the reference is no longer there. So, a reference is passed, but it's not returned, so to speak. As long as you don't reassign the variable passed as a parameter, it'll behave as expected in the "pass-by-reference" model.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but if you don't desperately need recursion, you can use this:

```
function create(rad, x) // create(nod *&rad, int x) in c++
{
  var result = new nod();
  result.info = x;
  result.left = result.right = null;

  while (true) {
    if (x < rad.info) {
      if (rad.left) {
        rad = rad.left;
        continue;
      }
      rad.left = result;
      break;
    } else
      if (rad.right) {
        rad = rad.right;
        continue;
      }
      rad.right = result;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```