# Javascript combine two objects keeping references

Tags: javascript

A simple example of what I'd like to do:

```
data = {name: 'fred'};

newData = {};
newData.name = data.name;

newData.name = 'ted';

console.log(data.name); // I want this to be ted not fred
```

Is it possible in Javascript to edit the second object and have it modify the first? I'm using alloyui 1.5 (yui 3.4.0) and trying to merge objects to create a datatable so the data appears on a single row but it needs to be editable, so it needs to point back to the original object.

Is such a thing possible or will I need to use events to push the data back to the first object?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308624/pass-a-string-by-reference-in-javascript might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this if property of your objects is also an object. This works:

```
data = {name: {first:'fred'}};

newData = {};
newData.name = data.name;

newData.name.first = 'ted';

console.log(data.name.first) // outputs ted
```

Comment: But what if i told you 'fred' is an object :P

Comment: @ManuelGörlich doesn't matter, name.first will reference a new object then: http://jsfiddle.net/6H8VG/

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can make a new object reference of the first( your data object) as newData using javascripts Object(). **Changing either objects property reflects to the other**.

```
data = {name: 'fred'};

var newData = new Object(data);

newData.name = 'ted';

console.log(data.name);// outputs ted
```

you can read more about Object() [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: `new Object(data)` does not create a new object reference. you should note that `newData === data` in this example.

Comment: You don't need to that javascript passes objects by reference as default so
```data = {name: 'ted'};
newData = data;
newData.name = 'fred';``` would achieve the exact same thing.

I think what OP want is to copy various properties of ```data``` to ```newData``` without beeing both the same object. So he is still able to add properties to ```newData``` that should not be on ```data```. And thats not a big problem as long as the value is not an immutable object like a string.

Comment: As Manuel Görlich mentions, I'm trying to use various properties without it being the same object. I wasn't aware that strings were immutable so thanks Manuel.