# Locate new created elements

Tags: javascript

I noticed that when i try to get the new content from a div, the browser returns the old content of the div.

```
<div id="here">Old text</div>

<script>
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = "New text";
</script>
```

Now the div text has changed:

```
 <div id="here">New text</div>
```

But when i try to alert the innerHTML of the div, i get the old text.
Can you please tell me why, and how can i get the new text?

EDIT

Excuse me, i have provided a wrong javascript code. This is corect:

```
var text = document.getElementById('here').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = "New text";
alert(text); // returns "Old text"
```

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you show how and in which order you set and get the text and show it?

Comment: it's can't be. Show us a complete code

Comment: It sounds like you probably assigned the old value to a variable, and are alerting the value of that *never-updated-since-then* variable.

Comment: Change the order of the first and second rows. First change the innerHTML of 'here' and then define the text variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a string by reference in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308624/pass-a-string-by-reference-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note here that `text` is not a live reference to the `innerHTML` property of `#here`. It's a one-off assignment that won't be kept up to date on its own. You'll need to re-assign the new value, or alert the `innerHTML` property directly:

```
var text = document.getElementById('here').innerHTML;
document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = "New text";
alert(text);
```

Let's look at another approach:

```
var here = document.getElementById( "here" ); // This is a reference
here.innerHTML = "New Text";
alert( here.innerHTML ); // This will always be the actual contents
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! 
Is it possible to update the variable from my code?

Comment: @Marian07 Sure, you can keep it up to date too: `document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = text = "New Text";` Note the double-assignment. Regardless what approach you take, you should keep a reference to `#here` so you don't have to keep calling `getElementById`.